Issue with PurchasesHybridCommon Pod Version Conflict in Expo React Native Project
I’m facing a version conflict issue with the PurchasesHybridCommon pod in my Expo React Native project while integrating RevenueCat. Here's the error message I'm receiving:
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "PurchasesHybridCommon":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    PurchasesHybridCommon (= 13.0.1)

  In Podfile:
    RNPurchases (from `../node_modules/react-native-purchases`) was resolved to 8.2.0, which depends on
      PurchasesHybridCommon (= 13.2.0)

It suggests:
You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `PurchasesHybridCommon` inside your development pod `RNPurchases`. 
   You should run `pod update PurchasesHybridCommon` to apply changes you've made.

I have tried running pod update PurchasesHybridCommon and pod install --repo-update, but the issue persists. Could you please advise on how to resolve this version conflict?
Thank you for your help!

Delete ios/pod.lock file and then

cd ios && pod install


I managed to resolve the issue by modifying the package.json file to lock the react-native-purchases version to 8.0.1:
"react-native-purchases": "8.0.1"
